# Problem with re.split() , data extraction from a string (splitting a string)

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, data-science

I have been trying to split this string but it only gives me the last character of the username I want. for example

[image]

in this dataset I want to separate the username from the actual message but after doing this code-

```
#how can we separate users from messages 
users = []
messages = []
for message in df['user_message']:
    entry = re.split('([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])+#[0-9]+\\n', message)
    if entry[1:]:
        users.append(entry[1])
        messages.append(entry[2])
    else:
        users.append('notif')
        messages.append(entry[0])
        
df['user'] = users
df['message'] = messages
df.drop(columns=['user_message'], inplace = True)

df.head(30)
```

I only get

[image]

Could someone please tell me why it only gives me the last character of the string i want to split and how I can fix it? thanks a lot. This means a lot

Comment: `'([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])+#[0-9]+\\n'` should be `r'([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])+#[0-9]+\\n'`. Otherwise you need 2 levels of backslash escaping, one for Python string literals and one for r.e. metacharacters.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting is not really the string operation you want here.  Instead, just use `str.extract` directly on the `user_message` column:

```py
df["username"] = df["user_message"].str.extract(r'^([^#]+)')
```

The above logic will extract the leading part of the user message, from the beginning, until reaching the first hash symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a lot simpler, by just using `string.split()` and setting the `maxsplit` to 1. See the example below.

Note that regex is very useful, but it's very easy to get incorrect results with it. I advise to use a online regex validator if you *really* need to use it. As for the actual regex, your `+` is in the wrong place. You need move it inside the group. I used [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) for testing...

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+)#[0-9]+\\n
```

`string.split()` example:

```py
line = "keikeo#2720\nAdded a recipient.\n\n\n"

user, message = line.split('\n', maxsplit=1)
print(user)
print(message)
```